# System.ArgumentException: The relation is not parented to the table to which this DataView points

Tags: asp.net

I have following requirements,
1. Need to show distinct apName.
2. For every apName, show rates.

I have tried this so far,

on .cs page

```
protected void btn_ViewClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  
//bind the repeater control, with the Data Table 
            rptApartmentName.DataSource = rate.GetAllApartmentRates();
            rptApartmentName.DataBind();
        }

        private void rptApartmentName_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
            if ((item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
            {
                Repeater rptRates = (Repeater)item.FindControl("rptRates");
                DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)item.DataItem;
                rptRates.DataSource = drv.CreateChildView("apartment_rate");
                rptRates.DataBind(); 
            }         
        }
```

and on aspx page,

```
<!-- start parent repeater -->
<asp:repeater id="rptApartmentName" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptApartmentName_ItemDataBound">
   <itemtemplate>
      <b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"apName") %></b><br>

      <!-- start child repeater -->
      <asp:repeater id="rptRates" runat="server">

         <itemtemplate>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "rate")%><br>
         </itemtemplate>
      </asp:repeater>
      <!-- end child repeater -->

   </itemtemplate>
</asp:repeater>
<!-- end parent repeater -->
```

please somebody suggest, what is wrong with this code, thanks in advance. I am using Asp.Net 2010.

Stack Trace:

```
Line 96:             Repeater rptRates = (Repeater)item.FindControl("rptRates");
Line 97:             DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)item.DataItem;
Line 98:             rptRates.DataSource = drv.CreateChildView("apartment_rate");
Line 99:             rptRates.DataBind(); 
Line 100:        }
```

I have got error on line 98, as  System.ArgumentException: The relation is not parented to the table to which this DataView points.

Comment: what error are you getting? be more clear about the problem

Comment: sure, I am getting this error: System.ArgumentException: The relation is not parented to the table to which this DataView points. on line:  rptRates.DataSource = drv.CreateChildView("apartment_rate");

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that I added my childTable before my parentTable to the DataSet that I bound to the parentRepeater. Once I reversed this (first adding the parentTable and then the ChildTable to the dataSet), the childview was created as expected and my nested repeater worked.